# Can I match the height of a formset input with a button?

Tags: html, django, bootstrap-4, django-forms

I'm currently making a todo list using Django model formsets. I came across a problem when trying to list each form in the formset with a delete button next to it. Here's a picture of what it looks like now:
[image: List of forms in formset with delete buttons next to them]
When looked at closely, the spacing and height for each form are slightly different than the spacing and height for each delete button. The buttons are slightly larger and more spaced out than the forms. Here's my views.py:

```
def dashboard(request):
user = request.user
todo_list = Todo.objects.filter(user=user).all()
UpdateFormSet = modelformset_factory(Todo, fields=('item',))
if request.method == 'POST':
    formset = UpdateFormSet(request.POST, queryset=todo_list)

    if 'delete' in request.POST:
        items_to_delete = request.POST.getlist('delete')
        deleted_items = Todo.objects.filter(pk__in=items_to_delete).delete()

    if 'update' in request.POST:
        if formset.is_valid():
            instances = formset.save(commit=False)
            for instance in instances:
                instance.user = user
                instance.save()
            return redirect('dashboard')



formset = UpdateFormSet(queryset=todo_list)
if not formset:
    formset = UpdateFormSet()

context = {
    'current_user': request.user,
    'formset':formset,
    'items':todo_list,
}
return render(request, 'users/dashboard.html', context)
```

Template:

```
<form method="POST">
                {% csrf_token %}
                <fieldset class="form-group">
                    <legend class="border-bottom mb-4 pt-3">ToDo Items</legend>
                    {{ formset.management_form }}
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-6">
                            {% for form in formset reversed %}
                            {{ form.id }}
                            <div class="py-3">
                                {{ form.item }}
                            </div>
                            {% endfor %}
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-6">
                            <div class="input-group">
                                <div class="input-group-append">
                                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-sm btn-success my-3" name="update"><i class="fas fa-plus"></i>
                                    </button>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            {% for item in items reversed %}
                            <div class="input-group">
                                <div class="input-group-append">
                                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-sm btn-danger my-3" name="delete" value="{{ item.pk }}">
                                        <i class="far fa-trash-alt"></i>
                                    </button>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            {% endfor %}
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </fieldset>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <button class="btn btn-outline-info" type="submit" name="update">Save</button>
                </div>
            </form>
```

I can't seem to align each form with its delete button. I'm guessing the two for loops are interfering with that. Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: Did you try using `flexbox` for the wrapper of each row? This would allow the contents to stretch height to match each other

Comment: I haven’t tried that but I will. Thanks!

Comment: The problem I'm having trying the flexbox is I can't put the input box and button in the same row because they are in their own for loops.

Comment: If you mean there are multiple buttons, just wrap them in a parent element and make it conform to the flexbox